# cannot perform FILEREAD operation on an unopened file or LOB

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

I have inserted a `BFILE` attachments, when download it throws

```
ORA-22289: cannot perform FILEREAD operation on an unopened file or LOB
```

Can you please help me out?

Comment: There are [examples in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96591/adl12bfl.htm); is there something specific you don't understand?

Comment: Yes i tried the samples, But My Image not attached.Actually my oracle installed in different machine, Using my SQL Developer i created the connection and from my local C drive i attached one file, the record get inserted, but when i tried to retrieve/download the file it gets failed

Comment: How to check , whether my attachment got inserted in Oracle